# First build: mobo lights up, but no CPU fan or monitor activity

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, computer-building, heatsink

I am having trouble booting up my first PC build. It uses compatible suggestions from [Logical Increments](http://www.logicalincrements.com/), which include the following:

- [Case: Cooler Master Trooper (Rev. 2)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GN5IKA8)
- [Motherboard: ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012NH074G)
- [CPU: Intel Boxed Core I7-6700K 4.00 GHz 8M Processor Cache 4 LGA 1151 BX80662I76700K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012M8LXQW)
- [Power supply: EVGA SuperNOVA 750 P2 80+ PLATINUM, 750W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010HWDP48)
- [Heatsink: Noctua CPU Cooler [NH-U12S]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C9EYVGY)
- [RAM:G.SKILL 16GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015FY431W)
- [Graphics: Gigabyte AMD 4096 Bit 4GB HBM PCI Express 3.0 Graphics Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017KI1JJU)
- [SSD: SanDisk Extreme PRO 240GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KHRYRNM)
- [HDD: Seagate 1TB Desktop HDD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005T3GRNW)

When I switch on the power, the mobo LEDs come (and stay) on, and all the case fans spin just fine. However, the heatsink fan does not spin at all, and there is no output to the monitor. In trying to trace the issue, I have tried:

- Ensuring all plugs are in tight, and various moving around (e.g., CPU vs. CPU2 on power supply. I think the CPU fan may itself be faulty, since neither CPU_FAN nor CPU_OPT socket makes it work)
- Both HDMI and VGA connections to monitor; both give "No Singal". Verified that monitor works with my laptop, and tried plugging HDMI into GPU instead, which also gave "No Signal"
- Tried one, the other, and both of my 8GB RAM sticks in the slots suggested by mobo manual; no configuration so far seems to work
- Removed graphics card entirely; still no output

So maybe something is wrong with the mobo itself, or even the CPU? I'm afraid to move the CPU from its delicate(?) spot, but if it's the likely culprit I can try to re-seat it.

What else might I be missing?

Comment: Did you plug in a PC speaker to hear if it gives an error code?  All motherboards produce beep sequences that represent what the error is when they can.

Comment: What happen if you remove both RAMs? Can you test your RAM and PSU on the another system? In my opinion, it's occurred because of RAM or PSU.

Comment: This sounds pretty low level, so try reinstalling the CPU. ensure that the CPU V12 rail(s) (4-pin or 2x 4-pin) are plugged in.

Comment: I don't have a speaker, but I tried some headphones without luck. To make the audio work in the first place, is there a cable that needs to go into the system panel?

Comment: I also tried re-installing the CPU..._and realized that I had neglected the CPU installation tool!_. So it might be that while just setting it in the socket, I wasn't aligned and ended up bending something :-(

Comment: Normally CPUs only fit one way round